# When I call setLeftBarButtonItem,something like "Screen Edge Pan Gesutre Recognizer" just can not work

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I know it is a feature of iOS7 added to UINavigationController to pop current ViewController by panning from the screen's left edge. And I found there is a "Screen Edge Pan Gesture Recognizer" in Object Library. But when I implement it by code, its behavior is slightly different from the previous one.
I want to know why this behavior just gone when I call setLeftBarButtonItem method. Hopes someone could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution to my problem.

```
class MyViewController : UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem(backButtonItem, animated: true) // disable the   gesture recognizer
        // the magic code
        self.navigationController?.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = self
    } 
}
```

Comment: Your UIViewController has to conform to UIGestureRecognizerDelegate and set navigationController?interactivePopGestureRecoginzer.delegate to self.

Comment: For the reference: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/12354/custom-back-button-ios7-broken-back-gesture

Comment: hi, if the MyViewController is the rootview can you edge swipe back and then tap some area of the app, it will freeze / crash the app